# Prevent Flask + jinja2 from converting a long integer into a decimal

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

[a total python noob] 
I'm rendering a template and passing in a dictionary:

```
d = {'id':3423444989845}
```

but when I'm doing like so `<div id="{{d['id']}}">` instead of getting `<div id="3423444989845">` the HTML renders like this: `<div id="3.423445e+12">`.

How can I prevent this? (my temporary solution was to pass the id as a string, but I was hoping to keep it an integer.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure its not actually a float?

Comment: well, might be, I don't really know. Just to give some background: the number is actually a `var id = new Date().getTime();` that I POST to the DB (mongo).

Comment: can you post the whole code that populates id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your ID is a float, not an integer (JavaScript's `Date#getTime` returns a float and I'm willing to wager that MongoDB is also storing the value as a float.)  If you want it to be treated as an integer you should convert the value you are given by JavaScript to an integer in your Python code:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    try:
        # Remember, *never* trust user input
        # This is most likely a number but you are not guaranteed that
        data_id = int(request["id"])
    except ValueError:
        abort(400)
    # If we got here, we have a valid int
    # Insert data into MongoDB
```

Comment: well that's odd. No it works as I want and I haven't changed a thing yet. The problem itself also appeared all of a sudden. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: I ran into the same problem somewhere else and turning the number to an integer solved it. Thanks man